# AutoHotkey | RegExMatch

Tags: character, autohotkey

I need help to figure out what kind of characters I have to put to save the right var with RegExMatch.

```
RegExMatch(LLine, "(.*) :  !hello", Name)
    SendInput, y
    sleep, 1000
    SendInput, Hello %Name1%, how are you?{enter}
```

So the chat output is like this for example: `*SPEC* TEST TEST :  !hello`

I want the var to be: `TEST TEST`

`(.*)` saves everything in front of  `:  !hello`

How can I make him to not save the `*SPEC*` part?

Also, not everyone has that `*SPEC*` inside their name. When I'm not in Spec of course, he wont show it in the chat.

As well if someones name is just 1 word like "TEST", I want him to save the single word as the var.

---

I hope you guys understand what I mean and can help me, I would be really thankful!

Comment: if you want to replace the string with a regEx part of it, use `regExReplace`

Answer (score 2):

## Description

```regex
i)^(?:\*spec\*)?\s*([^:]*)\s+:\s+!hello
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

I'm using the case insenstitve flag for this regex which is applied in AutoHotKey as `i)`.

## Example

**AutoHotKey Sample Code**

```
InputString := "*SPEC* TEST TEST :  !hello"
RegexMatch(InputString, "i)^(?:\*spec\*)?\s*([^:]*)\s+:\s+!hello", Match)

strMessage := "InputString = '" . InputString . "'"
strMessage .= "`nName = '" . Match1 . "'"
MsgBox, % strMessage
```

**AutoHotKey Output**

```
---------------------------
DesktopAutomation.ahk
---------------------------
InputString = '*SPEC* TEST TEST :  !hello'
Name = 'TEST TEST'
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

**Live Demo**

Regex Example: https://regex101.com/r/tP1uI5/1

**Sample text**

```
*SPEC* TEST TEST :  !hello
```

**Sample Matches**

```
MATCH 1
1.  [7-16]  `TEST TEST`
```

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
i)                        set case insensitive mode
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \*                       '*'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    spec                     'spec'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \*                       '*'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^:]*                    any character except: ':' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  :                        ':'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  !hello                   '!hello'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thank you so so so much! That really helps me out a lot!